# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_dtype_counts'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to see the counts of the datatype in a DataFrame using `get_dtype_counts()` method but it is giving error. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5))
df
```

**Output**

```
    0
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

**Error**

```
df.get_dtype_counts()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-aa9a46562585> in <module>()
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5))
----> 2 df.get_dtype_counts()
      3 # df

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_dtype_counts'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [20]: import pandas as pd
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...:
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5))

In [21]:

In [21]: df.dtypes.value_counts()
Out[21]:
int64    1
dtype: int64
```

`.get_dtype_counts()` is deprecated since version 0.25.0

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`.get_dtype_counts()` is [deprecated since 0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get_dtype_counts.html), use `.dtypes.value_counts()` instead